# Reusable nib for multiple classes

Tags: ios, uikit, nib

I have a case in which I would like to use one NIB (for UITableViewCell to be precise) for multiple classes. I have tried to define outlets as 'File owner' as then instantiate the cell, but I always receive crash, where xCode telling me that class is not key/value compliant for some outlet.

So my question is: is it possible to use one NIB, define outlets and then instantiate nib & class in a way, that Outlets are linked to the class?

The code I have tried to use:

`let cell = UINib(nibName: "SampleTableViewCell", bundle: nil).instantiate(withOwner: DummyTableViewCell.self, options: nil).first as? SampleTableViewCell`

The SampleTableViewCell nib has UITableViewCell defined for cell class (default) and FileOwner as NSObjet (default again). All IBOutlet are linked as FileOwner.

Comment: Why exactly do you want to do that?

Comment: did you register the nib file?

Comment: @mag_zbc As I wrote: define UI once and implement for example two different cells. I know that I can define base cell and then subclass, define UI twice, define UI programatically... but I would like to reuse nib if it is possible

Comment: @Aditya in the concrete case this has nothing to do with UITableView (yet). If it would be easier - the same issue appears with regular view. Image defining NIB once, reusing it twice.